# Flutter Http Content-Type

Tags: api, http, flutter, file-get-contents, dropbox-api

I want to upload an image to dropbox using their API with http in flutter but dropbox API content-type is 'application/octet-stream', when I tried using http content-type like this(appplication/json) but not working, How can I use this application/octet-stream as my Http content type in flutter

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Dropbox-API-problem/m-p/362407#M20605 ]

Answer (score 2):

Try to do something like this:

```
http.post(url,
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"},
  body: your-image-data
```

Comment: I have a lot of headers so, I have to use Map. like this                                    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
        'Content-type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'User-Agent': 'api-explorer-client',
       // 'Dropbox-API-Arg': '{"path": "/EasyBay/Project1/image.txt"}',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer' + token
      };                                                                                                                   
       Yet, It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

in dio

```
Dio dio = Dio()..interceptors.add(InterceptorsWrapper(
  onRequest: (RequestOptions options) async {
    options.headers
      ..addAll({
        'platform': 'xxxx',
        'token': 'xxx'
      });
    return options;
  }
))
```